# Living in italy with old paper UK licence, need to update

Tags: uk-citizens

How do I go about updating my UK licence when I don't have a photo card licence. I can put a uk a address of my parents for delivery etc. but can I do this, what do I need to complete etc.

Comment: If you live in Italy it's likely you need to exchange it to an Italian one. Preferably before Brexit

Comment: In the UK, drivers' licenses are issued to residents. If you don't live in the UK, then you're going to have to...lie...on the DVLA application.